# How to make gnuplot handle fractions as float in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

If I use gnuplot inside pgfplots it doesn't seem to recognize fractions properly as floats, thus I have to type `3/7.` instead of `3/7` which is annoying. Is there a way to change this behaviour globally?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[no markers,samples=100]
    \addplot gnuplot {2/7*x^2};
    \addplot {2/7*x^2};
    \addplot gnuplot {2/7.*x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but probably not, that's documented behaviour for Gnuplot. You can swap the order to `2*x^2/7`, and it will work, but I suspect it's better to get into the habit of adding `.0`.

Comment: There was a thread about this on the Gnuplot-info mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/gnuplot-info/thread/20171115014404.GT70095%40rb.t41t.com/#msg36115674

Comment: I know that it's a gnuplot issue. However my hope was that one might configure pgfplots such that it automatically passes 3/7.0 to gnuplot if I provide 3/7. That's why I am asking here (and not in a gnuplot forum).

Comment: BTW, x*x is MUCH fast then x^2=exp(2*log(x))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality in pgfplots.

---

If you use `gnuplot` in order to improve accuracy and speed, you may be interested in the following suggestion: you can use `lualatex` in order to compile your documents. In this case, `pgfplots` makes a good effort to compute math expressions by means of lua -- which results in high accuracy and high speed. The only prerequisite is to write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` (or newer) into your preamble.

If `pgfplots` figures that your plot contains TeX code or something which is unsupported by the current lua backend, it will automatically fall back to the `pdflatex` implementation without any user action.